# Cauchy Sequence of Differentiable Functions Implies Cauchy Sequence of Derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone provide a proof of the fact that if I have a sequence of differentiable functions that is Cauchy and converges uniformly on some interval $[a,b]$, then the sequence of their derivatives must also be Cauchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no one can provide a proof of that because it's false. Consider the functions $\frac1n\sin(nx)$.

Comment: Or consider $\frac1n\sin(n^2x)$ for even more ferocious derivatives.

Comment: Interestingly, if you [replace differentiable with holomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem#Uniform_limits), the statement *does* hold.

Comment: @angryavian Right, provided you have uniform convergence on a big enough set, like an open disk, so that you can do contour integration in it.  Even with holomorphic functions, it won't work if you have uniform convergence only on, say, an interval of the real axis (as in my example).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out,　Andreas.

Comment: Oops, yes, thanks for the clarification @AndreasBlass